# Custom jQuery in Drupal works in chrome, firefox, but not IE 7 8 or 9 - please help debug

Tags: jquery, drupal, user-interface

I've written some custom jquery and jquery ui for a project, which can be found here:

http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com/node?device=desktop

You'll notice there is a slide bar at the top. Sliding it all the way to the right causes a pop up to display an iphone or ipad with mobile theme. This works great in firefox and chrome, but not in any version of IE greater than 6 (I don't care about 6, mainly 7 and 8).

I'm not getting any errors at all in debugging the script with firebug or IE development toolbar.  This is stumping me. Can anyone see why the handle is not sliding in IE?

Also, the solution cannot be to upgrade my jQuery or jQuery ui because of dependencies with Drupal. But if you can pinpoint that is the problem, let me know and suggestions on how to get around it.  Sorry for the slow site, caching is turned off while I debug.

Thanks!
Blue

Comment: Can you post your js+css for the slider?

Comment: @calum Here is the jquery [link](http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com/sites/all/themes/tao/js/iphone-unlock.js) and here is the css [link](http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com/sites/all/themes/tao/css/style.css) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ey up! It wont show any errors because its not a javascript bug. its a css bug. it you mouseover the slider button in ie notice the cursor doesnt turn into a pointer.

I believe its to do with your relative and absolute positioning.

Try adding z-indexes or removing uneeded relative positions. also try adding display block to your a tag as its a link with no text in at the mo and by default they display inline.

Hope this helps!

add display:block; to #unlock-handle